# is there difference between releasing two semaphores in the same or reverse order as they are acquired?

Tags: concurrency, mutex, semaphore

Generally, if two semaphores  are acquired one after the other, is there difference between releasing them in the same order or the reverse order as they are acquired?

In the following solution to the third readers-writers problem from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem#Third_readers%E2%80%93writers_problem,

- in `reader()`, why are `serviceQueue` and `rmutex` released in the same order as they are acquired?
- does it matter whether  `serviceQueue` and `rmutex` are released in the same or reverse order as they are acquired?
- How does the code improves over [the code for the first readers-writers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem#First_readers%E2%80%93writers_problem), in [avoiding starving a writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem#Third_readers%E2%80%93writers_problem)?
- Is `serviceQueue` a counting semaphore? what shall it be initialized to?

Code:

```
int readcount;                // init to 0; number of readers currently accessing resource

// all semaphores initialised to 1
semaphore resource;           // controls access (read/write) to the resource
semaphore rmutex;             // for syncing changes to shared variable readcount
semaphore serviceQueue;       // FAIRNESS: preserves ordering of requests (signaling must be FIFO)

//READER
reader() {
<ENTRY Section>
  serviceQueue.P();           // wait in line to be serviced
  rmutex.P();                 // request exclusive access to readcount
  readcount++;                // update count of active readers
  if (readcount == 1)         // if I am the first reader
    resource.P();             // request resource access for readers (writers blocked)
  serviceQueue.V();           // let next in line be serviced
  rmutex.V();                 // release access to readcount
    
<CRITICAL Section>
//reading is performed
    
<EXIT Section>
  rmutex.P();                 // request exclusive access to readcount
  readcount--;                // update count of active readers
  if (readcount == 0)         // if there are no readers left
    resource.V();             // release resource access for all
  rmutex.V();                 // release access to readcount
}

//WRITER
writer() {
<ENTRY Section>
  serviceQueue.P();           // wait in line to be serviced
  resource.P();               // request exclusive access to resource
  serviceQueue.V();           // let next in line be serviced
    
<CRITICAL Section>
// writing is performed
    
<EXIT Section>
  resource.V();               // release resource access for next reader/writer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that the service queue becomes available one nanosecond before the readcount queue. So someone getting on the servicequeue can request access to the readcount queue one nanosecond before it becomes available, but there are situations where you have to wait a lot longer.

It would be preferable to release the reader queue as soon as it’s not needed anymore, but would in this case make no difference. You may be able to write code where it *does* make a difference.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how does the code improves over [the code for the first readers-writers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem#First_readers%E2%80%93writers_problem), in [avoiding starving a writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem#Third_readers%E2%80%93writers_problem)?

Comment: Is `serviceQueue` a counting semaphore? what shall it be initialized to?

Comment: Once the writer has got hold of the service queue, all the readers can’t get hold of it, so no new readers can squeeze ahead of the writer.